# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when i try to change the label's text value

Tags: javafx, fxml

Here is a simple label project for javafx using fxml with netbeans. 
The problem is, when I use

```
StartFomulars.setText("abc");
```

It just gets an exception given below.

Here is the code for main,

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Start extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Prove Controller = new Prove();
        Controller.launchController(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The fxml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <GridPane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0">
      <children>
        <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
        <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <children>
            <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
            </GridPane>
          </children>
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="282.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="282.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="281.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="281.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
        <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <children>
            <Label text="Given: " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Label text="Prove: " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Goal: " GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="StartFomulars" text="StartFomulars" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Label fx:id="GoalFomular" text="GoalFomular" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
          </children>
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="457.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="125.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="802.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="790.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="188.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="156.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="364.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="364.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="186.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="43.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="915.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="915.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="539.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="165.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="359.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="157.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="582.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="563.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the code for controller,

```
package main;

import ast.LogicStatement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author zl2511
 */
public class Prove {

    private Parent parent;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;
    private List<LogicStatement> startStatements; 
    private LogicStatement goalStatement;

    @FXML
    private Label StartFomulars, GoalFomular; 

    public Prove() throws IOException { 

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Prove.fxml"));
        //fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            parent = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

            scene = new Scene(parent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        StartFomulars.setText("abc");

    }


    public void launchController(Stage stage) {

        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle("start");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.hide();
        stage.show();

    }

    public void redirectprove(Stage stage, List<LogicStatement> startFormulas, LogicStatement goalFormula) { 

        this.startStatements = startFormulas; 
        this.goalStatement = goalFormula; 

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.hide();
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Here is the exception,

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure is pretty unusual. It's more normal to structure an Application class, FXML file, and controller as shown in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm).

As you have things set up, there is no connection between your controller class and the FXML. So the fields annotated `@FXML` never get initialized.

The way this is intended to work, is that the `FXMLLoader`'s `load(...)` method will parse the FXML file. If there is a controller set on the loader, then any elements with a `fx:id` attribute defined will be injected into matching `@FXML` annotated fields in the controller.

There are basically two ways of setting a controller on the `FXMLLoader`. The first is to have a `fx:controller` attribute defined on the root element of the FXML file. This will cause the FXML loader to create a **new instance** of the specified class, and use that as its controller. Note this won't work in your case, because you want the controller to be the `Prove` instance you have already created, not a new instance of the `Prove` class.

The second way is to create an `FXMLLoader` instance (instead of relying on the `static` `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method you are currently using), and call `setController(...)` on that instance. So (I think) uncommenting the

```
//fxmlLoader.setController(this);
```

line will get this to work.

You may need to separate the declarations of the fields too, i.e.:

```
@FXML
private Label StartFomulars ;
@FXML
private Label GoalFomular;
```

(It might work without that change, I've never tried it the way you have it.)

You should probably also take out the `try {...} catch (...) {...}` structure in the constructor for `Prove` (since you declare it `throws IOException` anyway), or at least do something in the `catch` block. Right now if an exception occurs loading the FXML you won't know about it, and you will just plough ahead and try and set the text of the label.