# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on label.setText

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm sure I'm close from answers, but I can't see my mistakes anymore.

I'm trying to load custom listCell for a listView.

The problem is, when I use

```
labelArticle.setText(article.getNewsSite());
```

It just gets an exception given below. Means I get it for each new listCell .

The controller :

```
public class ArticleCellController extends ListCell<Article> {
    @FXML
    private ImageView icon;
    @FXML
    private Label labelArticle;
    @FXML
    private Label titleArticle;
    @FXML
    private Label resumeArticle;
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;


    private FXMLLoader mLLoader;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Article article, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(article, empty);

        if(empty || article == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (mLLoader == null) {
                mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/articleCell.fxml"));
                mLLoader.setController(this);
                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            labelArticle.setText(article.getNewsSite());
            titleArticle.setText(article.getTitle());
            resumeArticle.setText(article.getSummary());

            // setText(null);
            setGraphic(gridPane);
        }

    }
}
```

The fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane fx:id="gridPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="30.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="120.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="31.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="labelArticle" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
        <Label fx:id="titleArticle" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
        <Label fx:id="resumeArticle" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

The Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.bfh.spacenews/ch.bfh.spacenews.ArticleCellController.updateItem(ArticleCellController.java:46)
    at ch.bfh.spacenews/ch.bfh.spacenews.ArticleCellController.updateItem(ArticleCellController.java:14)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:478)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListCell.indexChanged(ListCell.java:337)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1742)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1726)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1852)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2755)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1207)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1784)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at ch.bfh.spacenews/ch.bfh.spacenews.MainFX.start(MainFX.java:38)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ch.bfh.spacenews.MainFX
```

I checked this post [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when i try to change the label's text value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276425/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-when-i-try-to-change-the-labels-tex)
But I didn't forget to uncomment  `mLLoader.load();`

So what could possibly go wrong?

**Update :**
With the debugger I have a first error in the try-catch:

```
try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

LoadException on "..."/target/classes/articleCell.fxml:8, which I assume is produce by the missing fx:controller... but... that's a non sense... right?

Comment: I would not recommend `extends ListCell<Article>`. Having the `Controller` extend `ListCell` just seems a bad practice to me.

Comment: The most relevant exception is usually the __innermost__ one; here, it's `NullPointerException` on line 46 of your `ArticleCellController` class. That is the problem: Your ` labelArticle` is never set.

Comment: @rzwitserloot But, I dont think so, because it muss be set to the fxml template with the fx:id